# What's the best short cut for this in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, syntax

```
padColor = [bgColor bgColor bgColor];
padColor = reshape(padColor,1,1,3);
```

How to do the above in a more compact way(less code/replication)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ones(1,1,3)*bgColor
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, using repmat:

```
padColor = repmat(bgColor,[1,1,3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one is:

```
padColor(:,:,1:3) = bgColor
```